# Is there a Unit Testing Framework for Starbasic?

Tags: unit-testing

Okay I know this is a really lame question because Starbasic is a really lame language, but...does anyone know of a unit testing framework for Starbasic?  Sometimes we don't have the luxury of doing things in a sensible language like .net, because sometimes 80% the project is already written... :-D

Comment: Yeah I really doubt there is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there probably isn't, you could probably create one with relatively little work. While a few nice features like reflection might be missing from basic as a language, you could whip up a basic testing framework of a kind with less than a hundred lines of code. There are examples like CppUnitLite that aren't very complicated and could be used as inspiration.